# Recursive expression in Report Builder 3

Tags: reporting-services, expression, recursive-query

I've got some data in report, grouped by year/month.
Is there any way to refer to previous month data with recursive way?
I need to implement such formula:

> Backlog = last_month_backlog + (sum_of_open – sum_of_close)

where last_month_backlog is (sum_of_open – sum_of_close) from the previous month.
For example

- Februrary: 5 open, 4 close, last_month_backlog:2 -> Backlog = 2 + (5 - 4) = 3
- March: 7 open, 3 close -> Backlog = 3 + (7 - 3) = 4

What I've tried so far is:

```
=((IIf((Fields!month_number.Value > Month(Fields!close_time.Value) and (Fields!month_number.Value-2) < Month(Fields!close_time.Value)),(sum(Fields!number_of_open_cases.Value) - sum(Fields!number_of_close_cases.Value)),0)) + (sum(Fields!number_of_open_cases.Value) - sum(Fields!number_of_close_cases.Value)))
```

but it doesn't work correctly...

So the issue is how to add data from the previous month to the current one.
I was trying also with such expression:

```
=IIf(Fields!month_number.Value = Month(DateAdd(DateInterval.Month,-1,Today())) ,sum(Fields!number_of_open_cases.Value) - sum(Fields!number_of_close_cases.Value),0)
```

still no luck... Any ideas how to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think RunningValue() is what you want. Running Value just keeps a cumulative total of some values you define, so if we tell it to Sum the backlog for each month like this;

```
=RunningValue(Fields!sum_of_open.Value - Fields!sum_of_close.Value, Sum, "Year")
```

I'm assuming "Year" is the name of the Row Group that groups on Year, if not you'll need to change that.

Edited to reflect comments trail.

Comment: I've got it grouped in columns on [full_year] and then child group on [month_number]. I guess on my example it should be like that: =RunningValue((Fields!number_of_open_cases.Value - Fields!number_of_close_cases.Value), Sum, "month_number") but it seems not to work... I'm getting "The Value expression for the text box ‘Textbox21’ has a scope parameter that is not valid for an aggregate function.  The scope parameter must be set to a string constant that is equal to either the name of a containing group, the name of a containing data region, or the name of a dataset.".

Comment: In the bottom right pane, that says "column Groups", what does the [month_number] bar say? That's what need to be used as the last parameter of RunningValue()

Comment: Ok, got it, I should use name of a group instead of value which is grouped on. But it shows exactly the same what I can get with using only "=sum(Fields!number_of_open_cases.Value) - sum(Fields!number_of_close_cases.Value)" , means, present month backlog. Please see the screen: http://i.snag.gy/Ch39r.jpg. Instead of 24, 4 and 10, I need to see there (24 + backlog from month number 8), (24+4), (4+10).

Comment: Ummmm, try setting the third parameter to the name of the Year grouping rather than the Month grouping. I'm shaky on how this function works exactly :P

Comment: Excellent, glad you got it sorted!